# Only ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION not working for lowest accuracy location

Tags: android, expo, android-location

I was trying to reduce Android permissions to minimum. I used to have The `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and also `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. However I never used fine location. So I removed it. I did a build and installed locally and it worked fine, but after releasing to store it's not working. These are the only location calls I do. Anyone have any ideas why its not working with just coarse permission?

I am using Expo SDK Version 40.0.0 for React Native so here is my javascript (the java code it calls is below).

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

function getLocation() {

  try {
   return await Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync();
  } catch (error) {
    return await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.LocationAccuracy.Lowest
    });
  }

}
```

This is javascript that calls these java methods:

https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/LocationModule.java#L256

And:

https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/LocationModule.java#L276